# string с двойными кавычками в несколько строк?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019
Есть данные

```
{
  "product": "oil",
  "price": 544.13
}

string json = "{\"product\": \"oil\", \n  \"price\": 544.13}";
```

Как можно для удобства задавать также в несколько строк!?

```
string json1 = @"{'product': 'oil',  
              'price': 544.13}";
```

Но только с двойными кавычками? [дублирующего вопроса нет!!! Не нашёл]
Когда использую \" для задачи двойных кавычек внутри строки, компилятор не даёт разорвать строку.

Нужно:

```
string json1 = @"{"product": "oil",  
              "price": 544.13,
              "volume":11 }";
\" - не помогает
```

Comment: `@"""product"": ""oil"""`

Comment: @Alex в том ответе нет двойных кавычек внутри строки...  Там как раз в зачтенном ответе и сказано, что при переносе строки @ можно не заморачиваться со спец символами, КРОМЕ двойных кавычек...

Comment: @Alex извиняюсь. Трудности перевода!!! Спасибо!

Comment: Помещать сырой json в код - не самое лучшее решение. Оно вам точно нужно?

Comment: @Andrei Khotko, я новичок в шарпе и .net, изучаю. Приходится. Без этого тяжело. К стати, у самого такая же мысля была...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так. Переносы работают.

```
string json1 = @"{""product"": ""oil"",  
              ""price"": ""544.13"",
              ""volume"":11 }";
```

Answer (score 3):

Если Вам нужно получить на выходе корректный JSON, а объект заранее известен, попробуйте обойтись без работы со строками:

```
var obj = new
{
    price = 544.13,
    product = "oil"
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

При работе с анонимным типом будет удобно задавать значения полей, не используя кавычек. А далее, полученный объект конвертировать в JSON удобным способом, в данном случае через Newtonsoft

Comment: к сожалению, лучше не использовать преобразование такого вида. Например, человек как раз пишет тест и ему необходима строка json именно в коде, а не в файле или других ресурсах. И он как раз хочет проверить, как она будет преобразована или же на взаимодействие такой строки и, например, сервиса. Поэтому лучше дополнительыне пакеты не использовать в таких случаях.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Работа со строками может таить в себе множество "подводных камней". Поэтому для исключения банальной орфографической ошибки и предложен анонимный тип. Однако, выбор способа решения зависит от условий задачи. А в условии задача не описана подробно. Поэтому какое решение является правильным в данном случае нам понять не получится. Автор вопроса сам выберет наиболее подходящее для него.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу необычное, немного извращенное решение. Вместо экранирования кавычек будем использовать интерполяцию `$` и "буквальный идентификатор  `@`" **одновременно**. Доступно начиная с c# 6.0+ :

```
    const char q = '\u0022';
    var json1 = $@"
       {{
          {q}product{q}: {q}oil{q},  
          {q}price{q}: 544.13,
          {q}volume{q}:11 
       }}";
```

P.S. Не проверял работу на `.net framework`, только на `.net core`.

Comment: Извините, но это извращение чисто воды.

Comment: А по мне приятнее выглядит, чем многоковычность.. но больше нравится вариaнт @FreePainter34

Comment: @sombik сам вопрос извращение - добавлять в исходный код json в качестве константной строки. Я лишь хотел показать некоторые возможности языка, а не призывал к тому, что так стоит поступать.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Иногда реально необходимо использовать вот такие конструции. Например человек как раз и пишет тесты TDD для проверки работы JSON или же для других вариаций. Ему нет необходимости доставлять в проект еще дополнительныей пакет и его использовать. А то что Вы написали, можно переработать и сделать в StringBuilder с форматом отображения, но все равно не лишено смысла.

Comment: @sombik не могу себе представить ситуацию, когда в тесте нужно использовать сырой json. Разве что для парсера json. Не думаю, что автор занимается именно этим.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko собственно это я и имел ввиду. Могут быть еще как проверка данных, которые приходят в сервис(метод) ввиде строки, а далее с ней что-то происходит. На практике не раз такое видел, но лучше, конечно, такое выносить в отдельный ресурс файл или что-то еще. 
С моделями тоже не все так гладко.